# If a set is "not open", what is it?

Tags: general-topology

Physics background here, no formal pure maths education so please try to reply accordingly.

What are the possibilities for a set which is "not open"? Are they:

1)

closed

both open and closed

neither open nor closed

or

2)

closed

neither open nor closed?

In other words if a set is said to be "not open" does that mean that it could be both open and closed?

Accordingly for "not closed".

Or am I entirely confused?

Comment: If a set is said to be "not open", then all we know about it is that it is not open.  It could be closed, or it be not closed, but it definitely isn't open.  Thus (2) is correct, and (1) is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was after.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and enhance your question.

Comment: This is a common confusion - the naming is a little silly. The saying is "sets are not doors" (they don't have to be open or closed - and they can be both!)

Comment: Also have a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyD4p8_y8Kw).

Comment: Thanks Laufen. I don't feel so welcome with a minus one on my question. Maybe next time I'll go elsewhere.

Comment: Dear @Eva, Mathematicians are indeed a bit grumpy sometimes, especially towards Physicists, but please don't mind them too much.  I can say for myself that your question is very welcome here.

Answer (score 2):

Everything can happen!  For instance, in $\mathbb R$, with its usual metric:

$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
&\text{OPEN} &\text{CLOSED} \\
\hline
(0, 1) & \text{Yes} & \text{No}\\
[0, 1] & \text{No} & \text{Yes}\\
[0, 1) & \text{No} & \text{No}\\
\mathbb R & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes}
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1):

A very common mistake is thinking that a not open set is closed. This is false, e.g. $[2,5) \subset \mathbb{R}\ $ is not open and it is also not closed. This shows that: "Not open does not imply closed".

What *is* true is that the *complement* of an open set is closed.

So always be aware of this.

As to your question, Xander Henderson answered correctly in the comments: it can't be (1) because a not open set cannot be both open and closed because it cannot be open.

Comment: The terminology can definitely be a little confusing at first haha. But yeah, nice answer, ${+1}$

Answer (score 0):

A set can be open (if it's in the topology, by definition), closed (if its complement, the "outside" of the set in the whole space) is in the topology, both open and closed (if both are the case, for example in $\Bbb N$ with its natural topology inherited from $\Bbb R$), *all* sets are both open and closed, while in $\Bbb R$ in the usual topology *only* $\emptyset$ and $\Bbb R$ are both open and closed (as they are in any topology), but in general most sets will be neither open nor closed.

So not open does not imply anything else besides just that: it's not in the topology. It *could* still be closed, or not closed.

Ditto for non-closed sets: they could be open or not. Open and closed are just the simplest kind of sets topolgosts are interested in, also countable unions of closed sets ($F_\sigma$'s) get a special name, as do countable intersections of open sets ($G_\delta$'s). They play special roles too sometimes, e.g. in studying measures, points of continuity of functions etc.

Don't let language fool you: open is not an opposite of closed, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

A topological space is a pair $(X,T)$ where $X$ is a set and $T$ is a collection of some or all of the subsets of $X$ such that

(1). $X\in T$ and $\emptyset\in T.$

(2). If $S\subseteq T$ then $\bigcup S$ (which means $\cup_{R\in S}R\,$) is a member of $T.$

(3). If $S$ is a $finite$ subset of $T$ then $\cap S$ (the common intersection of the members of $S$) is a member of $T$.

The members of $T$ are called the open sets and their complements in $X$ are called closed sets. $T$ is called a topology on $X.$ Now $T$ could contain every subset of $X$ (Note that $X$ is a subset of $X$), in which case every subset of $X$ is open and closed ("clopen"). But it could also be that $T=\{X,\emptyset\}.$ It is common to say "a space $X$" as if everyone knew which possible $T$ was specified.

Comment: In the "standard" ("usual") topology on $\Bbb R$, "most" subsets of $\Bbb R$ are neither open nor closed, and the only open-and-closed sets are $\emptyset$ and $\Bbb R.$